# jquery autocomplete-ui not working with remote data

Tags: python, django, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i spend two days on this plugin, and no success - works only on local data array :(
i have a code (django/python) that generate json string ( valid - tested on http://jsonlint.com/ ) something like this:

```
[{"id": 7626, "value": "Jaros\u0142aw", "label": "Adrianowicz"}, {"id": 2702, "value": "Bo\u017cena", "label": "Baranowicz"}, {"id": 2542, "value": "Tomasz", "label": "Baranowicz"}]
```

my jquery code is:

```
$('#query').autocomplete({
 source: "/aut/",   //this generate json and working
 minLength: 2
 });
```

i check ajax example - geonames - and this working OK. any help?

Comment: Firebug show any errors in the browser, can you see it call the source and get a reply? Anything in the server error logs?

Comment: is your response mimetype set to mimetype="application/json" or mimetype="application/javascript" ? because sometimes people missing this.

Comment: in server logs nothing special:

    127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2011:20:01:19 +0200] "GET /aut/?term=now HTTP/1.1" 200 136

and of course i'm using "application/json" as mimetype

Comment: OK, its my stupid mistake, in django code, everything working good, firebug == my best friend now

Answer (score 0):

You can use any .ajax options inside autocomplete. Try this

```
$('#query').autocomplete({
 source: "/aut/",   //this generate json and working
 dataType: "json",
 minLength: 2
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

For the value of source, you can use a callback rather than the url of the page, as in this example:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache

Using a callback allows you to write your own success and error handling for the .ajax.  You will probably want to use .ajax and check the error.